# Getting the URL entered in browser before redirection in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to get the params of the URL originally entered in the browser. But angular "redirects" me automatically to `'/'`

For example, I enter this URL : `http://localhost:9080/#/test?param1=en&param2=55`

But I end up getting : `http://localhost:9080/#/`

```
var config = function (AppConfig, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                var params = $location.search(); //here : $location is already returning the wrong URL : http://localhost:9080/#/
                return config;
            }

        }
    });

};
```

Here is my only route :

```
$stateProvider.state('test', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'testView@' : {
                templateUrl: '/app/test/test.html',
                controller: 'test.controller',
                controllerAs: 'testVM'
            }
        }
    });
```

Why is that ? Is there a way to get the original URL ?

Comment: show your routes definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
document.URL;
```

Or

```
window.location.href
```